# Dynamic Fullscreen image splash page

Tags: html, image, image-size, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

i am trying to build a simple landing page for my website on bigcartel. 
i am trying to get it so that a fullscreen image takes up the whole page and directs to the product page after being clicked
after tons of research this is what i have come up with

```
<head>
<a href="/products">
<img title="click to enter" src="http://i.imgur.com/QC0IqJ9.gif"
style="width: 100%"; style="height: 100vh">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 <
body {
background: src="http://i.imgur.com/QC0IqJ9.gif" ;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
-->
<a {
 position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}>
</style>
   </a>
  {{ head_content }}
</head>
```

my problem is that i cannot get the image to stretch and fit depending on the browser resolution

Answer (score 0):

You have some really strange tags within your `<style>`, but I'm **assuming** they're part of Scrapy-Splash. The problem is specifically with your line `background: src="http://i.imgur.com/QC0IqJ9.gif";`. You're setting CSS, so you don't set the `src`, you set a `url()` as such:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/QC0IqJ9.gif");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)